# if and gotoif suddenly stopped working in Selenium IDE 2.9.1 Firefox 27

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

As the title says, it seems the target is simply ignored. Specifically:

```
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>&quot;${tvar}&quot;=&quot;Audio&quot;</td>
    <td>target1</td>
</tr>
```

tvar is a value that is grabbed from a table and Audio is the text I am looking for inside that value.

Comment: Without your selenium script, noone can answer your question

Comment: <tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>link=Service</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>storeTable</td>
 <td>css=table.enduserbody.7.0</td>
 <td>myvar2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>if</td>
 <td>&quot;${myvar2}&quot;==&quot;cname&quot;</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>addSelection</td>
 <td>id=availableList</td>
 <td>label=cname</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>//tr[8]/td[2]/input</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>endIf</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>name=apply</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: I wonder why it formatted it that way, but the idea is, grab info from a table, search for a specific piece of text in that info, and if present, do an action. If text defined is what I need, it simply ignores it for some reason. If text defined is the whole array, for example, cwatchcnamecread, then it looks for it, if it is part of it, for example, cname, it does not. Hope I am making sense here.